# how to link two fields with a connecting line when the two fields clicked.... in angularJs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, angularjs

i have 10 fields in the upper side , and have 10 fields in the bottom side , i need to two fields were connect with a line when i clicked two fields (one upper field and one bottom field) , in need to connect all pair of fields with a line in angularJs..

i need the all upper fields are connected with the bottom fields with a conective line. I click uppen one field and bottom one field to its connect with the line... it was present to the all fields.. its a click event..  in angularJS..

Comment: You could put a canvas between your upper fields and your lower fields, calculate the correct coordinates and draw [lines](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/canvas_lineto.asp) or [curves](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/canvas_beziercurveto.asp) into it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("plunker", []);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.top_span = [
    {
      name: "1",
    },
    {
      name: "2",
    },
    {
      name: "3",
    },
    {
      name: "4",
    },
    {
      name: "5",
    },
  ];

  $scope.bottom_span = [
    {
      name: "1",
    },
    {
      name: "2",
    },
    {
      name: "3",
    },
    {
      name: "4",
    },
    {
      name: "5",
    },
  ];

  $scope.lines = [];
  $scope.unline = {};
  // console.log("line", $scope.lines);
  // console.log("unline", $scope.unline);

  $scope.getPosTop = function ($index) {
    let element = document.getElementById(`1_${$index}`);
    element.style.transform = "scale(0.8)";
    let x = element.offsetLeft;
    let y = element.offsetTop;
    // console.log("Element X1: " + x);
    // console.log("Element Y1: " + y);
    if ($scope.unline["from"]) {
      return (
        ($scope.unline["to"] = { x: x + 15, y: y + 30 }), $scope.clearLine()
      );
    } else {
      $scope.unline["from"] = { x: x + 15, y: y + 30 };
    }
    // console.log("line", $scope.lines);
    // console.log("unline", $scope.unline);
  };

  $scope.getPosBottom = function ($index) {
    let element = document.getElementById(`2_${$index}`);
    element.style.transform = "scale(0.8)";
    let x = element.offsetLeft;
    let y = element.offsetTop;
    // console.log("Element X2: " + x);
    // console.log("Element Y2: " + y);
    if ($scope.unline["from"]) {
      $scope.unline["to"] = { x: x + 15, y: y };
    } else {
      return ($scope.unline["from"] = { x: x + 15, y: y });
    }
    // console.log("line", $scope.lines);
    // console.log("unline", $scope.unline);
    $scope.clearLine();
  };

  $scope.clearLine = function () {
    $scope.lines.push($scope.unline);
    $scope.unline = {};
  };
});
```

```css
.parent_span {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.parent_span_2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.top_span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.bottom_span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.line svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      data-require="angular.js@1.0.x"
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"
    ></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="parent_span">
      <div class="top_span" ng-repeat="c in top_span">
        <span id="1_{{c.name}}" ng-click="getPosTop(c.name)"
          ><svg fill="#000000" height="30px" width="30px" viewBox="0 0 490 490">
            <path
              d="M0,0v490h490V0H0z M430.1,332.9h-87.5v50.9h-33.1v50.9H180.4v-50.6h-33.1v-51.3H59.9v-278h46.7v66.5h38.5V54.8h40.8v66.5
         h38.5V54.8h40.8v66.5h38.5V54.8h40.8v66.5H383V54.8h46.7v278.1L430.1,332.9L430.1,332.9z"
            /></svg
        ></span>
        {{c.name}}
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="parent_span_2">
      <div class="bottom_span" ng-repeat="c in bottom_span">
        <span id="2_{{c.name}}" ng-click="getPosBottom(c.name)"
          ><svg fill="#000000" height="30px" width="30px" viewBox="0 0 490 490">
            <path
              d="M0,0v490h490V0H0z M430.1,332.9h-87.5v50.9h-33.1v50.9H180.4v-50.6h-33.1v-51.3H59.9v-278h46.7v66.5h38.5V54.8h40.8v66.5
       h38.5V54.8h40.8v66.5h38.5V54.8h40.8v66.5H383V54.8h46.7v278.1L430.1,332.9L430.1,332.9z"
            /></svg
        ></span>
        {{c.name}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="line">
      <svg>
        <line
          ng-repeat="line in lines"
          x1="{{line.from.x}}"
          y1="{{line.from.y}}"
          x2="{{line.to.x}}"
          y2="{{line.to.y}}"
          style="stroke: rgb(255, 0, 0); stroke-width: 2"
        />
      </svg>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).